# Searching in arraylists [JAVA]

Tags: java

I have 2 arraylists. One for License plates, 1 for kilometers (the indexes match).
In the first arraylist, there are multiple indexes with the same license plate. I want to make another arraylist of that but then just with 1 license plate, and then adding the kilometers driven. 
So if there's

```
arraylist1;arraylist2 
license 1; 500 
license 1; 600  
license 1; 300 
license 2; 100 
license 2; 100
```

it should give 2 arraylists saying the following

```
arraylist1;arraylist2 
license1;1400 
license2;200
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Just. Use. A. `Map`.

Comment: Also when i used a map, the same question remains. How to search in it for the same value then adding those.

Comment: You don't need to search a `Map` - you just ask it.

Comment: ehm could you pleasespecify that a little bit might be useful

Comment: and with the same keys it would be replaced right, not added

Comment: I have flagged your username for moderator attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Map, like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> sum = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for(int i=0; i<arraylist1.size(); i++){
    if(!sum.containsKey(arraylist1.get(i))) {
      sum.put(arraylist1.get(i), arraylist2.get(i));
    }else{
      sum.put(arraylist1.get(i), arraylist2.get(i) + sum.get(arraylist1.get(i)));
    }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: javaFiles\newFile.java:197: error: no suitable method found for write(Map<String,Double>)

Comment: any idea how to still have it as output? I use buffw.Write

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to *map* a `key` (the license) to a `value` (the kilometers). So just use a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html).

For example:

```
final List<String> licenses = List.of("license 1", "license 1", "license 1", "license 2", "license 2");
final List<Integer> kilometers = List.of(500, 600, 300, 100, 100);

final Map<String, Integer> sum = IntStream.range(0, licenses.size())
        .boxed()
        .collect(toMap(licenses::get, kilometers::get, Integer::sum));

System.out.println(sum);
```

Output:

```
{license 1=1400, license 2=200}
```

---

Using

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;
```

Comment: Thanks man! One question however, I do not know how many keys/values there are (cuz its reading it out of a csv file and the amounts might differ). Is this also possible to use in that case?

Comment: Allright, and would it also be possible to write it as output? Cuz as I remember you can't "write" integers into output files... Correct right?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a MAP with licence as key, and add the kilometers by searching the key.